# Is there a way to filter the AWS DynamoDb Stream before triggering lambdas?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, event-sourcing

So we have a couple of lambdas that listen to changes on the db, in every lambda we had to filter in the beginning because this particular lambda don't care about all changes just a particular one.

To be more explicit, we are applying event sourcing and lambdas are supposed to be event handlers. I want lambda A to be triggered ONLY when event A is inserted in the db rather than whenever an event is inserted! And same for lambda B and event B and so on.

In the time being we have a filter in the beginning of every lambda:

```
lambdaA handler:
const eventsToBeProcessed = events.filter(
   (event) => event.eventName === 'EventA'
);
```

Now that we have a good bunch of lambdas it doesnt make sense to trigger all of them when I need only to trigger one!

I'm not very experienced with AWS but I'm assuming the solution will either be:

- Being able to filter on DynamoDb Triggers
- Instead of making lambdas triggered by dynamodb, have a AWS service in between that's triggered on every change and it will know which lambda to trigger depending on what's the update

EDIT:

I was not very happy with the solution I marked as an answer, the main reason because the Single Point Of Failure in the design, also it will need to count on an SNS to do a publish/subscribe and SNS is not highly available and it can fail you if you are trying to have a highly available system (4 9s or so)

The solution I ended up adapting (for now at least) is that when I push my events into the event store, if I want to trigger a side effect, I will just push it into AWS' EventBridge (an Event bus with rules). The best part about the EventBridge is that you can set the rules you want, the bus you want, and then have (for example) Lambda A be invoked when the bus have Event A and so on.

Comment: You can't do this. Instead stream everything to a single lambda, and the lambda will distribute events to different lambda functions. Could use sns/sqs to decouple the first lambda from the rest.

Comment: @Marcin yes, this is what I expected, and this is what I meant in the 2nd solution, wasn't sure if it should be a single lambda or another AWS service

Comment: Sadly this is the only option. You can just think whether you want directly invoke other lambdas from the first one, or put the db events into sqs or sns before the other lambdas will process them.

Comment: What are exactly my options if I want to directly invoke the other lambdas? (Other than doing api calls thro the api gateway)

Comment: You can use aws api to invoke the other lambdas. If your function is in python, you would use boto3's [invoke](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke) method. You could invoke them asynchronously (i.e. invoke and don't wait for any return values). No need for api gateway for this to work. You would have to just add permissions to the first lambda's execution role to allow invoking other functions.

Comment: I'm mainly using ts but yes I'm pretty sure there is a similar boto3 for that. And yeah I'd obviously prefer not to use api gateway for that! Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is now a way to do that,

[https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/filtering-event-sources-for-aws-lambda-functions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/filtering-event-sources-for-aws-lambda-functions/)/

It's a new feature of lambda, it uses the same syntax as AWS Eventbdridge.

```sh
aws lambda create-event-source-mapping \
--function-name fleet-tire-pressure-evaluator \
--batch-size 100 \
--starting-position LATEST \
--event-source-arn YOUR_DB_STREAM_ARN \
--filter-criteria '{"Filters": [{"eventName": ["EventA"]}]}'
```

[You can refer to this documentation to know the exact syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns.html)

Comment: That's amazing! thank you for the update, I will see if I can actually update our solution because this is much more robust and easier (simpler)

Comment: does it only work for eventbrige? I can't find this configuration on Dynamodb trigger

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao

Yes.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventfiltering.html

"For Amazon Kinesis, Amazon DynamoDB, and Amazon Simple Queue Service (Amazon SQS) event sources, you can use event filtering to control which events Lambda sends to your function for processing. "

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao I think it's now possible,
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.Tutorial2.html

Answer (score 1):

I think it would make sense to have one Lambda function responding to additions to the DynamoDB stream, dispatching the events to the respective downstream functions.

```
                                         ------------
                                     -->  Function A
--------     ---------------------       ------------
 Stream  -->  Dispatcher Function                        
--------     ---------------------       ------------
                                     -->  Function B
                                         ------------
```

Comment: If I was to implement something like this, how can I escape the risk of having the dispatcher function a single point of failure? Since in this case all my lambdas will be triggered by the dispatcher/invoker

Comment: To be more explicit, the dispatcher function will need an SNS topic most likely and the other functions will subscribe by topic and this way everything will be filtered. AWS ensures their lambdas to be highly available but not sure if the same for SNS (again my AWS experience is kinda limited)